# react scroll bar issues while toggling the child component

Tags: reactjs, scrollbar

I came across a strange issues in react.

I have a parent container component which overflow is auto. see the below two images:
[image]

when I change the event type, and it will load the other component, this component contain many fields so there will appear scroll bar, as below:
[image]

when I change back to the "type-one" the first component(green one) layout become mess, some text box will line wrap

[image]

So, any one encountered this before? I guess the reason is the before scrollbar does not disappear so cause the issue, is there good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Set `overflow-y: overlay;`, and the scrollbar won't affect the layout when it appears.

Comment: It is great, that it indeed can works, thans a lot. But the overlay is not compatible in IE, I don't know the reason about it, I want find  a common solution for it.

Comment: @RonSmith Try changing the parent container's margin to `margin-right: -25px;`, or however wide the scrollbar is.